# Unable to create the Jquery Horizontal Ticker as mentioned in this website

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create the following as shwon in this webpage

http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Plugin-For-Horizontal-Text-Scrolling-Simple-Marquee.html

I created a small  fiddle with the code mentioned by the author

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="marquee-sibling"> Breaking News </div>
  <div class="marquee">
    <ul class="marquee-content-items">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wf43X/312/

But when i tried to run this i am getting the following error under browser console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: You are using the plugin in the wrong way. `:(`

Comment: Thank you Praveen , why is it wrong way i have copied the js as it is know ?

Comment: You cannot just like that run that function I guess. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle's javascript panel was just set with a 'load type' of `onLoad`. This was causing the plugin to initiate too late. Changing 'load type' to `No wrap` fixes the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Wf43X/326/